# Access user-defined object state using java reflection in @Aspect type class

Tags: java, reflection, aop, aspectj, pointcut

I have a class A which declare a static logger instance and then used in the method of the class.

```
class A {
  static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(A.class);
   person p = new Person();
   public void methodA(){
     // log.info("logging using apache commons logger");
      }
  }
```

I have another class B which is @Aspect type. Its method may trigger based on execution of A's method.

```
@Aspect
 class B{

  @Before(--execution of methodA() pointcut expression--)
   public void methodB(JoinPoint jp){
   // How to get the class A's logger instance to continue logging from same logger instance. As it will print class name   A in logs
        }

  }
```

I want to use the logger instance used in class A to log some message.

How can I get the object's state in Aspect class from joinPoint with reflection.

> I am not using spring framework, trying with aspectjrt apectweaver jars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `jp.getTarget()` to get the target instance for a non-static method or simply bind `target(targetObject)` to an advice method parameter. I am showing you the latter. Here is my [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

**Log4J configuration:**

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, consoleAppender
log4j.appender.consoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

**Helper class:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Person {}
```

**Driver application class:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

public class Application {
  private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(Application.class);
  private Person p = new Person();

  public void methodA() {}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application application = new Application();
    application.methodA();
  }
}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
  @Before("execution(* methodA()) && target(targetObject)")
  public void logMethodExecution(JoinPoint jp, Object targetObject) {
    // Filter for static logger, make it accessible and use it for logging 
    Arrays.stream(targetObject.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
      .filter(field -> field.getType().equals(Log.class) && Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers()))
      .forEach(field -> {
        try {
          field.setAccessible(true);
          ((Log) field.get(null)).info(jp + " -> logging using apache commons logger");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      });
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
[main] INFO  de.scrum_master.app.Application  - execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.methodA()) -> logging using apache commons logger
```

This kind of reflection stuff is quite ugly and might not work the way you wish in JMS-style modular applications without configurative precautions, if aspect and target class are not in the same module. At least, you could make your loggers public in order to avoid using `field.setAccessible(true)`.